# How to solve Github pages 404 problem when I use react router?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, deployment, react-router, github-pages

I try to deploy my typescript react app to Github pages, but every time when I access my URL, Github complains '404 there isn't a github pages site here.'

And I try to make my code simple, I just left the home page in my app, but it still complains.

If I don't use React router, it works. Why does it complain when I use react router?

**My Code**:

```
import Home from "./pages/Home" //rafce

import {
    BrowserRouter,
    Routes,
    Route,
} from "react-router-dom";

const Router: React.FC = () => {
    return <>
        <BrowserRouter>
            <Routes>
                <Route path="/" ><Home /></Route>
            </Routes>
        </BrowserRouter>
    </>
}

export default Router
```

**My JSON:**

```
{
 "homepage": "http://lsk21007.github.io/ohno",
 "name": "typescript-react",
 "version": "0.1.0",
 "private": true,
 "dependencies": {
   "@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core": "^6.1.1",
   "@fortawesome/free-regular-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
   "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons": "^6.1.1",
   "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome": "^0.1.18",
   "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
   "@testing-library/react": "^13.2.0",
   "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
   "@types/jest": "^27.5.1",
   "@types/node": "^16.11.36",
   "@types/react": "^18.0.9",
   "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.4",
   "bootstrap": "^5.2.0-beta1",
   "react": "^18.1.0",
   "react-bootstrap": "^2.4.0",
   "react-dom": "^18.1.0",
   "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0",
   "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
   "styled-components": "^5.3.5",
   "typescript": "^4.6.4",
   "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
 },
 "scripts": {
   "predeploy": "npm run build",
   "deploy": "gh-pages -d build",
   "start": "react-scripts start",
   "build": "react-scripts build",
   "test": "react-scripts test",
   "eject": "react-scripts eject"
 },
 "eslintConfig": {
   "extends": [
     "react-app",
     "react-app/jest"
   ]
 },
 "browserslist": {
   "production": [
     ">0.2%",
     "not dead",
     "not op_mini all"
   ],
   "development": [
     "last 1 chrome version",
     "last 1 firefox version",
     "last 1 safari version"
   ]
 },
 "devDependencies": {
   "@types/styled-components": "^5.1.25",
   "gh-pages": "^4.0.0"
 }
}
```

Thanks for your help!!

Comment: what url did you try ?

Comment: https://{myName}.github.io/{projectName}/